# Flutter: PlatformViewsController must be set before attempting to begin the frame Flutter. webview_flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webview-flutter

Android app is crashing with this exception "PlatformViewsController must be set before attempting to begin the frame Flutter" works fine in ios app. I am Using "webview_flutter: ^1.0.6"
Min SDK is greater than 19 here is my initState Method:

```
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
      if (Platform.isAndroid) {
          WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by upgrade my pre 1.12 Android projects.
[Upgrading pre 1.12 Android projects](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects)